# Naming a sheet a global string variable taken from a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to have successfully created this global string variable as I can print it in the MsgBox in the sub I am trying to use it in.

Current Code:

First Sub:

```
Option Explicit
Public storeName As String
Sub cleanupProdReq()

'takes storename as public variable
storeName = Cells(5, "C").Value
```

---

Next Sub:

```
Sub SelectActualUsedRange()

Dim w As Workbook
Set w = ActiveWorkbook

'opens requests workbook, names sheet today unles there is already one

Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\***\Documents\***\***\Supply Chain\Requests")

Dim wsTest As Worksheet
Const strSheetName As String = storeName
```

When I run this it highlights the last occurrence of 'storeName' and gives the error: "Constant Expression Required". Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Comment: You could remove `Const` from `strSheetName`.  It's really not a constant because it can change depending on the contents of your cell.

Comment: You're assigning a *constant* to a *variable*. A *constant* needs to be *constant*, i.e. its value determined at compile-time. Solution: declare it as a *variable*, since it's *variable*, not *constant*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Const strSheetName As String = storeName
```

The value of a `Const` must be determined at compile-time.

You're assigning it to a variable, whose value is only determined at run-time.

Use `Dim` instead of `Const` to declare `strSheetName`, and the compiler will be happy.